# Multilingual Messages

Tags: django

I have written the following code to show server side error messages on client side

```
messages.error(request , 'Authentication Failed.')
```

Which works file. I would like to load the message from Message file to keep all the messages in one place also I want to load images based on the language.

I explored Message File option in DJango but it looks like it translates the string by itself but I want to define myself and load them. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question, but an example for you could be this:

```
# file text_messages.py
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

MY_MESSAGE = _('Auth failed')
```

Then in the script where you should use that message:

```
import text_messages

messages.error(request, text_messages.MY_MESSAGE)
```

This is all in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/internationalization/)

Then, of course, you need to run `django-admin.py makemessages --locale=en,de` and provide a way to switch correctly languages in your views. Is this what you where after?

Comment: YES this is what I was looking. One more question, is this mandatory django-admin.py makemessages --locale=en,de or can I manually create one more file called text_messages_de.py and use it ?

Comment: If you use the `makemessages` command (options are `--locale` to specify a list of locales or `--all` which creates locales based on your `LANGUAGE` variable set in `settings.py`), django creates for you  `.mo` files, that contain the original string and an empty version of the same string that is a placeholder for your translations. You should use this method, since then switching between languages is easier. With a `messages_<language>.py` file, you have to bloat your scripts with a bunch of `if language == 'de' import...`, which is not the best (and correct) way of doing this.

Comment: Many Thanks !! So in the view I should set request.session['django_language'] = 'en-US' which will take US English version of Message file and If I change this value to request.session['django_language'] = 'en-UK' it will take UK Message file automatically. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Give a look at the docs, it's really simple once you read those :)